# Set event handler to Weblogic unmashaller

Tags: jaxb, eclipselink, weblogic12c

I have some web service interfaces which uses WL JAXB to for XML processing. I need to perform following operation of Web Logic JAXB unmarshaller.

Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();

unmarshaller.setEventHandler(validationCollector);

Any one know how to do it? Or is it possible?

Thank you in advance.

Lasith.

PS: I am using Weblogic 12c. With Eclipselink Moxy.

Answer (score 0):

I think that I'm missing something...

Why don't you simply collect the event?

```
unmarshaller.setEventHandler(
                    new ValidationEventHandler() { 
                        public boolean handleEvent(ValidationEvent event ) {
                            validationCollector.collectEvent(event);

                        }
                });
```